# Faker for Laravel Seeder

Tags: php, laravel, faker, laravel-seeding

I have a table `users` in a one-many relationship with a table called `videos`. I want to seed the two table without loosing data integrity. This is what I did below:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
return [
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'email' => $faker->email,
    'username' => $faker->unique()->userName
];
});

$factory->define(App\Video::class, function(Faker\Generator $faker){
    $user = factory(App\User::class)->create();
    return [
        'title' => $faker->city,
        'link' => $faker->domainName,
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'description' => $faker->sentence(40)
    ];
});
```

So now all I have to do is create a `VideoTableSeeder` and run the amount I want. I feel like the way I am handling it is not good enough so I would like to know what better way I can do it. Especially, I want the videos to be more than users rather than the same amount, in the one I had done they will all be the same amount.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the documentation the section [Adding Relations to Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#model-factories)

> Adding Relations To Models
>
> You may even persist multiple models to the database. In this example,
>   we'll even attach a relation to the created models. When using the
>   create method to create multiple models, an Eloquent collection
>   instance is returned, allowing you to use any of the convenient
>   functions provided by the collection, such as each:
>
> `$users = factory(App\User::class, 3)
>              ->create()
>              ->each(function($u) {
>                   $u->posts()->save(factory(App\Post::class)->make());
>               });`